# DistributionFitTest[] for custom distributions in Mathematica

Tags: statistics, wolfram-mathematica, probability

I have PDFs and CDFs for two custom distributions, a means of generating RandomVariates for each, and code for fitting parameters to data.  Some of this code I've posted previously at:

[Calculating expectation for a custom distribution in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296455/calculating-expectation-for-a-custom-distribution-in-mathematica)

Some of it follows:

```
nlDist /: PDF[nlDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_], 
   x_] := (1/(2*(alpha + beta)))*alpha* 
   beta*(E^(alpha*(mu + (alpha*sigma^2)/2 - x))* 
      Erfc[(mu + alpha*sigma^2 - x)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma)] + 
     E^(beta*(-mu + (beta*sigma^2)/2 + x))* 
      Erfc[(-mu + beta*sigma^2 + x)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma)]); 

nlDist /: 
  CDF[nlDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_], 
   x_] := ((1/(2*(alpha + beta)))*((alpha + beta)*E^(alpha*x)* 
        Erfc[(mu - x)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma)] - 
       beta*E^(alpha*mu + (alpha^2*sigma^2)/2)*
        Erfc[(mu + alpha*sigma^2 - x)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma)] + 
       alpha*E^((-beta)*mu + (beta^2*sigma^2)/2 + alpha*x + beta*x)*
        Erfc[(-mu + beta*sigma^2 + x)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma)]))/ 
   E^(alpha*x);         

dplDist /: PDF[dplDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_], x_] := 
  PDF[nlDist[alpha, beta, mu, sigma], Log[x]]/x;
dplDist /: CDF[dplDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_], x_] := 
  CDF[nlDist[alpha, beta, mu, sigma], Log[x]];

nlDist /: DistributionDomain[nlDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_]] := 
 Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}]

nlDist /: 
    Random`DistributionVector[
    nlDist [alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_], n_, prec_] :=
    RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[alpha], n, 
        WorkingPrecision -> prec] - 
      RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[beta], n, 
        WorkingPrecision -> prec] + 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], n, 
        WorkingPrecision -> prec];

dplDist /: 
    Random`DistributionVector[
    dplDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_], n_, prec_] :=
    Exp[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[alpha], n, 
         WorkingPrecision -> prec] - 
       RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[beta], n, 
         WorkingPrecision -> prec] + 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], n, 
         WorkingPrecision -> prec]];
```

I can post more of the code if someone needs to see it, but I think the above gives a good sense of the approach so far.

Now I need a way to use DistributionFitTest[] with these distributions in something like this:

```
DistributionFitTest[data, dplDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40],"HypothesisTestData"]
```

Ah, but this doesn't work.  Instead I get an error message that starts out as:

> "The argument
>   dplDist[3.77,1.34,-2.65,0.4] should be
>   a valid  distribution..."

So it appears that DistributionFitTest[] doesn't recognize these distributions as distributions.

I don't see how using TagSet would help in this instance, unless one can use TagSet to give  DistributionFitTest[] what it needs to identify these custom distributions.

Can anyone advise me of a way to get this to work?  I'd like to use DistributionFitTest[] with custom distributions like this or find some work around to assess goodness of fit.

Thx -- Jagra

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since this question has come up many times, I think it's prime time to furnish some recipes for how to properly cook a custom distribution for v8.

Use `TagSet` to define for your distribution:

1. `DistributionParameterQ`, `DistributionParameterAssumptions`, `DistributionDomain`
2. Define `PDF`, `CDF`, `SurvivalFunction`, `HazardFunction`
3. Define random number generation code by coding Random`DistributionVector

Doing so will make everything but parameter estimation work for your distribution.

Your mistake was that `dplDist` had no `DistributionDomain` definition, and both `nlDist` and `dplDist` did not have 
`DistributionParameterQ` and `DistributionParameterAssumptions` definitions.

I added to your definitions the following:

```
dplDist /: DistributionDomain[dplDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_]] := 
 Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}]

nlDist /: 
 DistributionParameterQ[nlDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_]] := ! 
  TrueQ[Not[
    Element[{alpha, beta, sigma, mu}, Reals] && alpha > 0 && 
     beta > 0 && sigma > 0]]

dplDist /: 
 DistributionParameterQ[dplDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_]] := ! 
  TrueQ[Not[
    Element[{alpha, beta, sigma, mu}, Reals] && alpha > 0 && 
     beta > 0 && sigma > 0]]

nlDist /: 
 DistributionParameterAssumptions[
  nlDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_]] := 
 Element[{alpha, beta, sigma, mu}, Reals] && alpha > 0 && beta > 0 && 
  sigma > 0

dplDist /: 
 DistributionParameterAssumptions[
  dplDist[alpha_, beta_, mu_, sigma_]] := 
 Element[{alpha, beta, sigma, mu}, Reals] && alpha > 0 && beta > 0 && 
  sigma > 0
```

And now it worked:

```
In[1014]:= data = RandomVariate[dplDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40], 100];

In[1015]:= DistributionFitTest[data, dplDist[3.77, 1.34, -2.65, 0.40],
  "HypothesisTestData"]

Out[1015]= HypothesisTestData[<<DistributionFitTest>>]
```

Comment: Nice! I think you could add this one (along with more details, if you wish) to [**our little ToolBag post**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4198961/353410) under the _Undocumented (or scarcely documented) Features_ section.

Comment: Thoughtful, informative, and revealing of what goes on under the hood. I wonder if whomever writes the tutorials could provide a detailed one on this entire subject?  It might also cover fitting parameters, moments, etc. - all the things one needs to get custom defined distributions to work as seamlessly as possible with Mathematica.  Again, many thanks -- Jagra

Comment: Does the same apply for LogLikelihood? Basically, do you have to use TagSet to define every possible function over the custom distribution?

Comment: @jfelectron Yes, the same holds for `LogLikelihood`

Comment: @Jagra The Wolfram Technology Conference 2011 presentation from the workshop 'Create Your Own Distribution' can now be downloaded from [here](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/mathematics-and-statistics.html)