# NodeJS x-ray web-scraper: how to follow links and get content from sub page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, x-ray

So I am trying to scrape some content with node.js x-ray scraping framework. While I can get the content from a single page I can't get my head around on how to follow links and get content from a subpage in one go.

There is a sample on x-ray github profile but it returns empty data if I change the code to some other site.

**I have simplified my code and made it crawl the SO questions for this sample.**

The following works fine:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202531/minimizing-nexpectation-for-a-custom-distribution-in-mathematica', '#content', [{

  title: '#question-header h1',
  question: '.question .post-text'

}])
(function(err, obj) {

  console.log(err);
  console.log(obj);

})
```

This also works:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://stackoverflow.com/questions', '#questions .question-summary .summary', [{

  title: 'h3',
  question: x('h3 a@href', '#content .question .post-text'),

}])
(function(err, obj) {

  console.log(err);
  console.log(obj);

})
```

but this gives me empty details result and I can't figure out what is wrong:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://stackoverflow.com/questions', '#questions .question-summary .summary', [{

  title: 'h3',
  link: 'h3 a@href',
  details: x('h3 a@href', '#content', [{
    title: 'h1',
    question: '.question .post-text',
  }])

}])
(function(err, obj) {

  console.log(err);
  console.log(obj);

})
```

I would like my spider to crawl the page with listed questions and then follow the link to each question and retrieve additional information.

Comment: Can find some answers related to this issue here: [x-ray scraping secondary urls related question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609440/node-x-ray-crawling-data-from-collection-of-url/39632464)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So with with some help I figured out what the problem was. I am posting this answer in case somebody else might have the same problem.

Working example:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://stackoverflow.com/questions', '#questions .question-summary .summary', [{

  title: 'h3',
  link: 'h3 a@href',
  details: x('h3 a@href', {
    title: 'h1',
    question: '.question .post-text',
  })

}])
(function(err, obj) {

  console.log(err);
  console.log(obj);

})
```

Comment: hmm, are you sure you pasted the correct code? Still can't get mine to work. Doing exactly the same thing, has exactly the 3 symptoms you've described in the question..

Comment: can you provide the kind of result you get from this query?

Comment: looks like this is an issue for other people. So I'm wondering how you got this thing working? https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray/issues/65

Comment: does it work if you just copy paste the code above? I will try it again as soon as I get home and will get to you with the results.

Comment: I tried running your code but the details properties is not been returned. Is it still working for you? Do you know if this nested crawling behaviour has been deprecated?

Comment: did you run the code I have provided above or something else, I just tried it and works fine for me. Did you got any error?

Comment: this code still works for me, are you using the same code and trying to scrape SO?

Comment: Not working for me either, I copy pasted your answer but I'm getting `undefined` as the output.

Comment: Nnot working here for whatever reason. (x-ray 2.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

version 2.0.2 does work.. there is a current issue in github here to followhttps://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray/issues/189